# jQuery - overwrite delay() action?

Tags: jquery, delay, slidedown, slideup

I have this code for an error message that overlaps the page. I just added the click listener - I want it to skip the delay and close right away if it's clicked. However, nothing happens. If I use .hide() in the click listener, it works. But I want to transition it out smoothly.

Any ideas?

```
// Flash messages effect
$("#FlashMessage").slideDown('250').delay(3000).slideUp('250');

// Hide flash message when clicked
$("#FlashMessage").click(function(){
    $("#FlashMessage").slideUp('250');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `#FlashMessage` is an actual Flash Object, it might be grabbing input and not issuing the event as expected.

I might be wrong though, but a possible solution might be to use `.focus()` instead of .click()`

Try having a image not a flash, and test with that, if it works. I'm right and the flash is denying the event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Nah, it's just a div with text. I see what's happening now. When I click, it just adds the new command to the end of the queue. So I need to somehow cancel the existing command, and replace it with the new one. Cancel out the delay...

Comment: Hmz, understood. Try: `$("#FlashMessage").stop(true,true).slideUp('250');`

Answer (score 0):

jquery.delay is not possible to skip. Use js timeout methods instead

```
$("#FlashMessage").slideDown('250');
window.setTimeout( function(){ $("#FlashMessage").slideUp('250'); },3000);

// Hide flash message when clicked
$("#FlashMessage").click(function(){
    $("#FlashMessage").slideUp('250');
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp